# App stops at Splash screen

Tags: phonegap-build, phonegap, splash-screen

I have implemented a splash screen in my PhoneGap Build hybrid app using the following code but when the app opens it just gets stuck at the splash screen until I tap the back button or tasks button on my cellphone and then only the next screen appears i.e. my welcome page.html appears. If I don't tap / press any key then it just keeps on showing me a loader along with the splash at the background.

```
 <splash src="splash.png" platform="android" />  


<splash platform="android" qualifier="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
<splash platform="android" qualifier="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
<splash platform="android" qualifier="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
<splash platform="android" qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />

<splash platform="android" qualifier="land-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
<splash platform="android" qualifier="land-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
<splash platform="android" qualifier="land-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
<splash platform="android" qualifier="land-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using this value as `false`  so setting it to `true` made it work.

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
```